# Why does converting with "%x" in Python not yield results with an 0x prefix?

Tags: python

```
# Write a function that does a decimal to hexadecimal conversion.
# Hint: Make use of "%x" for hexadecimal format.
def dec2hex(num): 
  return "%x" %  num
```

my answer returns 22 instead of 0x22. Why?

Comment: Why would you expect anything else? `0x%x` if you want the prefix.

Comment: ...but seriously -- questions of the form "why does X do Y?" aren't very answerable when Y is what X is designed to do. The only answer one could give is "because it was built that way". Now, to be sure, we could explain *why* building it that way was the sane and sensible thing, but that's somewhat aside the point.

Comment: What does you book say?

Comment: I need it to say 0x22, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Liz4rd, I already did. See my first comment.

Comment: The word missing from the "Hint" is "string"

Comment: can't use prefix 0x%x, because when 0 is num I get back 0x0 instead of 0x00

Comment: @Liz4rd, tried `0x%02x`? If you read the fine manual for format strings...

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a prefix, you are using the wrong method; the format you gave only converts integers straight to hexadecimal without any prefix or padding.

You can use the [`hex()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) to return hexadecimal representations with a `0x` prefix and no padding:

```
>>> hex(34)
'0x22'
```

Or you can use the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) and the `#x` format:

```
>>> format(34, '#x')
'0x22'
```

The `#` signals you want the prefix. You can ask it to provide 0-padding too, but you need to specify a field width that *includes* the prefix:

```
>>> format(34, '#06x')
'0x0022'
```

Here the `06` pads out the field to 6 characters, including the 2 for the prefix.

If your only option is to use the [`%` string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), you can still use that same trick

```
>>> '%#x' % 34
'0x22'
```

and padding is still available, with the same width caveats:

```
>>> '%#06x' % 34
'0x0022'
```

Comment: that's not using the hint. the answer requires using the hint.

Comment: @Liz4rd: yay for arbitrary coding exercises. I gave you all the options.

Comment: can't use prefix 0x%x, because when 0 is num I get back 0x0 instead of 0x00

Comment: @Liz4rd: perhaps you wanted to *specify you needed padding* then?

Comment: @Liz4rd: But you didn't specify that you needed to produce `0x00` for integer 0. That means you wanted 0-padding.

Comment: @Liz4rd: Either way, I spelled out the option to use `#` in `%` string formatting as well. For `0x00` you want `'%#04x'`.